# How to force a UIView to update

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am working on an application that is downloading JSON data from a server, and then displays it on a UIView. The view does get updated, it just takes about 15 seconds. I have tested to make sure it is not the download that is delaying the update, and if I change the view's background color as I am adding data it also waits to update. Am I correct in thinking that it is the view not updating, or is it something else? How do I force the view to update? Thanks.

```
var newView = CustomView(product: products[0],descriptive: false)
        contentView.addSubview(newView)

        let backHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0)
        let backWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let backXPosition = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant:0 )
        let backYPosition = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: colorLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([backHeight,backWidth,backXPosition,backYPosition])
```

This is how I am adding the items to the view.

Comment: How are you updating, is the returned block of your download happening on a background thread, and are you updating the UI from this background thread? All UI updates must be on the main thread.

Comment: How about placing some activity indicator until you get all data and then create the UI? Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the view does get updated, it just takes 10-15 seconds to do so after a println that should run after the views are added.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a sample of the code where you're displaying the data in the view?

You can trigger a view to update by calling

```
view.setNeedsDisplay() //Updates any drawing, including that in drawRect()
```

and

```
view.setNeedsLayout() //Triggers layoutSubviews()
```

But I don't think either of those will help as if you're adding new views they should show up without calling those. Unless you're on a different thread like Dharmesh suggested.

Make sure you're adding the views to the parent, and make sure you're setting a frame on them too as if they're labels they might not appear without a frame being set.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow forgot to add to the original post that the views do show up, just 10-15 seconds after a println that is the directly after where they are added

Answer (score 2):

When you got data from server you can update UI into view with main queue as shown in below code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //Update your UI here

}
```